# What's the name of these plastic connectors

Tags: renault, connector

I'm looking for the name for the plastic connectors you can see in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nwAZbA3yUoU&t=39s (at 0:39).

They consist of an outer part that can be squeezed together and put into the hole that you want it to go into, and then an inner part that you push into the outer part. The inner part then forces the outer part apart, which causes the whole thing to firmly stick in place.

In the video, the inner part is partly pulled from the outer part. The connector is used in a Renault Clio 3 to lock the front apron in place (together with what feels like a myriad of screws). I broke one of them during my attempted disassembly and would like to replace it…

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are plastic (expanding) rivets or at least that's what we called them.

Comment: These are also referred to as 'Scrivets'   (Google search: Plastic Scrivets)

Comment: Names do vary... Those tiny circlips used on small shafts were called "jesus clips" as in "jesus, where did that go..." :)

Answer (score 3):

On Amazon.com, they are called *Fender Bumper Clips, Auto Plastic Push Pins Nylon Rivets Retainer*. They come in various sizes, depending on what your manufacturer calls for. The size is determined by the size of the hole they are made for ... the ones in the picture below are considered 8mm:

[image]